# interfacing max30100 to 8051(I2C Communication Protocol)

Tags: i2c, 8051

I'm trying to interface heart beat sensor max30100 to 8051 for this purpose I should use i2c protocol. I'm using the following code for that but the sensor doesn't work even though i do the initializing

```
    ; Init i2c ports first
    lcall i2cinit
    ; Send start condition
    lcall startc
    ; Send slave address
    mov a,#0AEH
    acall send
    ACALL ACK
    ; after send call Carry flag has ACK bit
    ; If you want to check if send was a
    ; success or failure
    ; Send data
    mov a,#09H
    acall send
    ACALL ACK
    ; Send another data
    mov a,#0FFH
    acall send
    ACALL ACK
    ; Send stop condition
    acall stop






    lcall startc
    ; Send slave address
    mov a,#0AEH
    acall send
    ACALL ACK
    ; after send call Carry flag has ACK bit
    ; If you want to check if send was a
    ; success or failure
    ; Send data
    mov a,#07H
    acall send
    ACALL ACK
    ; Send another data
    mov a,#47H
    acall send
    ACALL ACK
    ; Send stop condition
    acall stop

    lcall startc
    ; Send slave address
    mov a,#0AEH
    acall send
    ACALL ACK
    ; after send call Carry flag has ACK bit
    ; If you want to check if send was a
    ; success or failure
    ; Send data
    mov a,#01H
    acall send
    ACALL ACK
    ; Send another data
    mov a,#0A0H
    acall send
    ACALL ACK
    ; Send stop condition
    acall stop


    SJMP $




    sda equ P0.0
    scl equ P0.1


i2cinit:
    setb sda
    setb scl
    ret


rstart:
      clr scl
     setb sda
     setb scl
     clr sda
     ret


startc:
    setb scl
    clr sda
    clr scl
    ret


stop:
    clr scl
    clr sda
    setb scl
    setb sda
    ret


send:
    mov r7,#08
back:
    clr scl
    rlc a
    mov sda,c
    setb scl
    djnz r7,back
    clr scl
    setb sda
    setb scl
    mov c, sda
    clr scl
    ret




ack:
    clr sda
    setb scl
    clr scl
    setb sda
    ret

nak:
    setb sda
    setb scl
    clr scl
    setb scl
    ret




recv:
    mov r7,#08
back2:
    clr scl
    setb scl
    mov c,sda
    rlc a
    djnz r7,back2
    clr scl
    setb sda
    ret
```

`

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'?

Comment: I mean led on sensor should start shining after this but it doesnt

Comment: (a) We cannot confirm whether your hardware design is good, as you have supplied no schematic and photos. How did you confirm that the hardware design is OK? (b) Personally, I'm not happy with several parts of your I2C code, including the I2C ACK. (c) One way you can provide enough information that *might* encourage others to help you, would be to use one of the cheap logic analysers sold on Ebay, Ali Express etc. and the open source Sigrok software (or one of the brand-name analysers, if you can afford it) and record what is happening on the I2C bus. Or use an oscilloscope & view the I2C bus.